# How to add Ubuntu Server packages to Ubuntu Desktop install

Tags: server

I'm trying to do a project. Project calls for Ubuntu so I install Ubuntu. Then I realize I was supposed to install Ubuntu Server but I installed Ubuntu Desktop.

Seems like it's no big deal as they're the same at the core and just different sets of packages (or at least that's what I've gathered as an Ubuntu noob - this is my first Ubuntu exposure).

I've tried googling and think I'm on the right track. I did:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel 
sudo tasksel
```

Now I'm looking at a screen with a bunch of packages I can choose to install. I see lots of options with "server" in the name (e.g. LAMP server, basic Ubuntu server, OpenSSH server, etc).

If I wanted to get an install similar to the standard Ubuntu server install, is "basic Ubuntu server" alone sufficient? Should I check all the server boxes? Start with "basic", go along with project and install stuff as needed? Something other than tasksel?

Comment: Yes, you can run "server" applications on Ubuntu Desktop. As for "check all the boxes", how about checking just the boxes you need? You can always go back to the terminal and install other packages later when you need them.

Comment: @Matigo Yeah, I may proceed and add as needed.  I guess I'm just a little initmidated by the project (seems complicated), not sure which packages I'll need yet, and kinda feel like I'm starting on the wrong foot.  But I'll plow ahead and see what happens.  Sounds like I'm on the right track with tasktel and can install any packages I need as needed from there.  Thanks!